# Relativistic Hamiltonian Formulations

Tags: symmetry, relativity, hamiltonian-formalism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hamiltonian mechanics and special relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32368/hamiltonian-mechanics-and-special-relativity)

The [Hamiltonian formulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) is beautifully symmetric. It's a shame that the explicit time derivatives in Hamilton's equations mean that the Hamiltonian formulation is not manifestly Lorentz-covariant. Is there any variant of the Hamiltonian formulation that is manifestly relativistic?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32368/2451 and links therein. Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38286/2451

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The covariant Hamiltonian version of relativistic classical or quantum mechanics of a single particle is just like the nonrelativistic one, with time replace by eigentime; see, e.g., Thirring's mathematical physics course.

A covariant Hamiltonian version of relativistic classical field theory is the multisymplectic formalism; see, e.g.,
http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9807080
http://lanl.arxiv.org/abs/1010.0337

A covariant Hamiltonian version of relativistic quantum field theory is the Tomonaga-Schwinger formalism; see, e.g.,
http://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0405006
http://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.0556
http://sargyrop.web.cern.ch/sargyrop/SDEsummary.pdf

Comment: Why are the formulations different?

Comment: @namehere: The single particle case is different from multiparticle case as there is no good definition of eigentimes for multiple particles. The two field versions are related, though one is well-developed in the classical case only, and the other in the quantum case.

Answer (score 2):

The SHP (Stuckelberg, Horwitz, Piron) Hamiltonian formulation is manifestly covariant. The equations of motion are

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x^\mu}{\mathrm{d} \tau} = \frac{\partial K }{\partial p_\mu}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}p^\mu}{\mathrm{d} \tau} = - \frac{\partial K }{\partial x_\mu}$$

$K=K(x^\mu,p^\mu)$ is the covariant Hamiltonian and $\tau$ the invariant evolution parameter (in general it differs from proper time $s$). The basic monograph is [Classical Relativistic Many-Body Dynamics](http://www.amazon.ca/Classical-Relativistic-Many-Body-Dynamics-Trump/dp/079235737X)

Comment: What is this evolution parameter?

Comment: $\tau$ is the relativistic generalization of the Newtonian concept of time. It is the parameter that sincronizes the many-particle correlations and labels each dynamical configuration in the covariant $8N$ phase space. $\tau$ was first introduced by Stuckelberg and Feynman although Hortwitz and Piron extended it to the many particle case.

Comment: The problem with the Horwitz-Piron approach is that it doesn't reproduce the standard results, and hence is irrelevant for the applications. It has too many observables.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier I'm not going to buy the book :(. What do you mean it has too many observables?

Comment: @namehere: The basic fields depend (in momentum space coordinates) on arbitrary 4-vectors $p$ rather than only on time/lightlike vectors on one or several mass shells.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9407075, http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0103136, http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0212036, http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9601021, and so on...

Comment: @namehere: The SHP theory is more complex than the simple approaches cited above by Neumaier because the SHP theory was designed to study __many-body motion__. The field-theoretic approaches cited by Neumaier work for "_a single particle_" or for trivial many-body problems which can be effectively treated as a collection of single particle problems.

Comment: @juanrga Arnold says your approach doesn't reproduce the 'standard' results. What say you?

Comment: @namehere: I believe that I have answered him above with a collection of links to published references regarding 'standard' results and predictions. Did not notice?

Comment: @juanrga: e.g., hep-th/9601021
''calculate certain elementary processes, including Compton scattering and Moeller scattering. These calculations lead to qualitative deviations from the usual scattering cross-sections''

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier: please continue reading where you stop: "_which are, however, small effects, but may be visible at small angles near the forward direction._" Can you provide a single reference with experimental data that disproves the predictions on the off-shell sector? Moreover, ordinary QED is recovered in the _on-shell limit_.

Comment: I only claimed that it does not reproduce the standard results.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier: Yes you did, but the four references given above show that the theory reproduces the standard results in well-defined limits. Moreover, the SHP theory was initially developed for applications __beyond the scope of field theory__. This is all very well explained in the Schieve's monograph cited in my answer.

Comment: It seems interesting, because I guess we can do everything same as just usual Hamiltonian dynamics in non-relativistic setting for well-given $s$ and parameters. I haven't read the monograph yet, but maybe there always be way to define $s$ right? Great enough..

Comment: @ChoMedit It's been a decade since I wrote that. Yes, we can continue to use Hamiltonian dynamics in relativity regimes, but the modern RHD (Relativistic Hamiltonian Dynamics) approach is much better than the manifestly covariant SHP approach.

Comment: @juanrga Oh, indeed. This was written in 2012. Very long time ago. Thanks for comment. But still, i have some question. The modern RHD approach, you mention now, is the thing mentioned by Arnold above? or are there some differences or developements?

Comment: @ChoMedit It is nothing of what he mentioned. See slide 13 on https://kipdf.com/relativistic-dynamics-in-nuclear-and-particle-physics_5aee2cdf7f8b9ad4178b4570.html